# Avoiding circular imports in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, circular-dependency

Help me please, I'm a bit frustrated and I still can't figure out how to plan ahead. A member on reddit told me that I can avoid circular imports by importing every module in one file, in my case it's `start.py`. I am probably not understanding imports correctly because I am getting an error. In `menu.py` I can't reach for my prompt (`prompt.py`) module (since it's imported only in `start.py`. I thought the way it works is if I get everything in one file that those imported modules will be able to speak to each other.

Can someone please explain why this is not possible?

These are the files:

### Files/modules:

```
|App/
  |- __init__.py
  |- start.py
  |- menu.py
  |- prompt.py
  |- locations.py
  |- error.py
```

### start.py:

```
import sys
import error
import menu
import prompt


print "\nMy little game"
print "=" * 27

menu.main_menu()
```

### menu.py:

```
def new_game():
    pass

def load_game():
    pass

def high_score():
    pass

def main_menu():
    print """
    1. New game
    2. Load game
    3. High score
    4. Quit
    """

    sel = prompt.number()

    if sel == 1:
        new_game()
    elif sel == 2:
        load_game()
    elif sel == 3:
        high_score()
    elif sel == 4:
        exit(1)
    else:
        error.type(2)
```

### prompt.py:

```
def number():
    try:
        while True:
            return int(raw_input("Type numbers only >"))
    except ValueError:
        error.type(1)
```

### error.py:

```
def type(number):
    errors = {
    1: 'Type numbers only',
    2: 'Does not exist',
    }

    print errors.get(number)
```

Comment: "A member on reddit told me that I can avoid circular imports by importing every module in one file" - either the person on reddit was mistaken (or lying), or you misunderstood what the person was saying. Importing everything in one file is not a solution to circular imports.

Comment: before trying to figure out how to avoid circular imports, read about how imoprt works...

Comment: Yeah well I'm a newbie programmer so I still don't know much. I'm just having so much problems with architecting my code.